# comments without mentions no longer show up in inbox messages

Tags: support, comments

Whenever I left a comment, I used to get a notification even if the user who responded didn't do @honey...but in the past ~2 months I'm getting less and less notifications for comment responses that don't include @honey or almost nothing!

I remember seeing it somewhere on meta that if you don't include the `@` but still write the comment *following* the previous one then it may or may not get to you and that was true it was more like a 50-50, but now it seems it's 10X more likely that you won't receive it ever. As a result I have to go through my own comments, click on them and see if the person has responded or not.

Can I change the settings? Is this something that is going to be fixed? Or if this is the intended behavior then can we send a system wide notification to all users and inform to include the `@`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are only two people on a comment thread (post owner + you), you will always get notified.

If you are the post owner, you will always get notified.

If you are not the post owner and there is another commenter who is not the poster owner - you will only be notified if you are @ notified.

This is because once there are three parties, it is not clear who one is responding to - so you have to clarify that with an @ notification.

Comment: That makes total sense. But even top reps make that mistake and don't include the `@mention`. I wish there was sort of up pop that would say... **hey make sure to do use `@mention` because there are 3 parties in the comments**. Should I open a new question for that, or there is already a feature request for that? I couldn't find an existing question...

Comment: You can open that, but I doubt this will happen - such a popup would just be intrusive, in my eyes. What happens when someone just wants to add a comment - not responding to anyone?

Comment: That's an edge case. It could be a placeholder or something. FWIW I'm sure you know of Gmail, it has several features you could enable that would remind you if you forgot to mention someone you usually mentioned in a group...or if you say the word attached but then forget to attach something. I'm not an expert on UI, but thinking there should be some way. SO could have similar features. Though I'm thinking about that fancy, a simple placeholder would make a lot of sense. There are many other intrusive examples on SO, like ones you get one when SO *thinks* your title isn't good.

Comment: So many rules @Oded

Comment: @bluefeet - mostly because we try to not have settings for things and have good defaults. Means the rules for things end up being complicated in order to have happen what most people *expect* to happen.

Comment: if there are only two people commenting on someone else's answer/question, do they need the `@` mention ?

Comment: @Honey - no, there is no need for it.